# Is there any way to Detect userInterations in Android fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, user-interaction

Could any one help me out with this situation.

I have implemented `OnUserInteraction()` method for Android Activity it is working fine for me.

But I want it for `Fragments` too.How can i able call  `OnUserInteraction()` or is there any another way to identify `userInteraction` with the `UI`.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Please [edit] with a [mcve]

Comment: I would like to Close my app if it is in idle mode (Background& foreground too).OnUserInteraction is working for me for activities,but i am unable to implement it in fragments.

Comment: The Fragment is held within the Activity. I don't understand why you think you need to implement the method there.

Answer (score 2):

@Sunil's answer causes java.lang.StackOverflowError so I corrected it. Below code works smoothly

Create a java class in your app named UserInterationListener and put below code there

```
public interface UserInteractionListener {
    void onUserInteraction();
}
```

Then create an instance variable in your activity, for this interface as below

```
private UserInteractionListener userInteractionListener;
```

Then implement a setter method for this variable, in your activity.

```
public void setUserInteractionListener(UserInteractionListener userInteractionListener) {
    this.userInteractionListener = userInteractionListener;
}
```

Now override the onUserInteraction method of your activity and if the listener variable is not null, invoke the interface method.

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    super.onUserInteraction();
    if (userInteractionListener != null)
        userInteractionListener.onUserInteraction();
}
```

Now, in your fragment class, implement UserInteractionListener as below

```
public myFragment extends Fragment implements UserInteractionListener
```

also override interface's method

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction(){
//TODO://do your work on user interaction
}
```

then in your fragment invoke your activity's userinteraction setter method like below

```
((YourActivity) getActivity()).setUserInteractionListener(this);
```

this last part is important.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to implement on touch listener in onViewCreated like so

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    view.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        requireActivity().onUserInteraction()
        true
    }
}
```

BTW this solution is in Kotlin

Answer (score -1):

There is another way around.

Create a listener in your activity as below

```
public interface UserInteractionListener {
    void onUserInteraction();
}
```

Then create an instance variable in your activity, for this interface as below

```
private UserInteractionListener userInteractionListener;
```

Then implement a setter method for this variable, in your activity. (You can even keep a List of eventlistener objects, if you want to pass same userinteraction to multiple consumers)

```
public void setUserInteractionListener(UserInteractionListener userInteractionListener) {
    this.userInteractionListener = userInteractionListener;
}
```

Now override the `onUserInteraction` method of your activity and if the listener variable is not null, invoke the interface method.

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    super.onUserInteraction();
    if (userInteractionListener != null)
        userInteractionListener.onUserInteraction();
}
```

Now, in your fragment class, register for events as below

```
((YourActivity) getActivity()).setUserInteractionListener(new YourActivity.UserInteractionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
        // Do whatever you want here, during user interaction
    }
});
```

Comment: method inside onUserInteraction () doesn't get called

Comment: @ClaudeHangui Which onUserInteraction() is not called? Activity's overriden method or the method from the anonymous inner class YourActivity.UserInteractionListener?

Comment: II'm trying to implement this workaround on spinner. So I followed the steps as shown above, and I register the event in my fragments, however the click on the spinner doesn't seem to work i.e it doesn't perform the expected behavior