# Is there any way to Detect userInterations in Android for single fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Player fragment where I am hiding a View in inactive state of fragment.
I am using setUserInteractionListener() in fragment to do this but the problem is it's applying on other fragments as well which I don't want.
Can anyone help me with this?
Is there any another option to interact with inactive fragment after 5 seconds?

I want to show below toast message only in player fragment but because of onUserInteraction() it shows on every fragment.

```
((MyActivity) getActivity()).setUserInteractionListener(this);
    runnable = () -> {
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User is  not interact from last 5 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 7000);
```

Comment: Attach some codes to your question pls

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting that view in other fragments is because `((MyActivity) getActivity()).setUserInteractionListener(this);` is listening to the activity the fragment is attached to, and not the fragment itself. A possible workaround for this could be to create a interface that the fragment implements. An example of this workaround is explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40842199/is-there-any-way-to-detect-userinterations-in-android-fragments)